# SQL equivalent of pandas DataFrame query

Tags: sql, pandas, google-bigquery

I'm trying to implement a SQL query which is equivalent to the pandas query:

```
df.groupby([df.ST_STATE, 'INVOICE'])['VALUE'].sum()
```

This returns all invoices and it's values for in group of states like this:

```
WV        114763      28.00
          116443      16.50
          116490      24.00
          116550      46.00
WY        100099       9.00
          100148       9.00
          100881      32.00
          101119      28.00
```

I've written a SQL query to get the same kind of result set from Google Cloud:

```
query = "SELECT State, Invoice, sum(Value) FROM ["+self.table+"] group by Invoice, State"
```

But it returns a standard result set:

```
    State   Invoice f0_
0   NY  100008  86.00
1   None    100335  64.00
2   NY  100685  60.00
```

How do I need to manipulate the SQL query to get results in the same shape as my DataFrame example?

Comment: are you referring to the multi-index feel where the state value is *not* repeated, but is instead in a pivot-table manner where repeated values are blank?

Comment: yes I want to make a multiindex dataframe as first

Comment: based on example data you provided in question  - please show expected result

Answer (score 2):

It looks like all you would need to do is change the order of the group by:

```
query = "SELECT State, Invoice, sum(Value) FROM ["+self.table+"] group by State, Invoice"
```

So the groupings will be applied in the same order as in your pandas example.

Comment: states still repeated

Comment: That this was your desired output isn't mentioned anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example in pure SQL (BigQuery Standard SQL) - hope you can "translate" it into respective pandas

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 'WV' state, [STRUCT<invoice INT64, value FLOAT64>
    (114763, 28.00),
    (114763, 16.50),
    (116490, 24.00),
    (116490, 46.00)
  ] info UNION ALL
  SELECT 'WY', [STRUCT<invoice INT64, value FLOAT64>
    (100099, 9.00),
    (100148, 9.00),
    (100099, 32.00),
    (100148, 28.00)
  ]
)
SELECT state, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT invoice, SUM(value) AS value 
    FROM UNNEST(info) i GROUP BY invoice
  ) info
FROM t
```

with result in same shape as original data and as below

```sql
Row state   info.invoice    info.value   
1   WV      114763          44.5     
            116490          70.0     
2   WY      100099          41.0     
            100148          37.0
```

Note: I slightly modified your data example in order to have something for grouping